# E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-pr2-arm-navigation

Tags: ros, inverse-kinematics, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to proceed with [this](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_kinematics/Tutorials/Tutorial%202) tutorial but when I run `sudo apt-get install ros-electric-pr2-arm-navigation` I get the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ros-electric-pr2-arm-navigation
```

Help would be appreciated. :)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232762/e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-electric-pr2-arm-navigation/) by [meep](https://answers.ros.org/users/25977/meep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-04-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In the package name that you're trying to install, you should probably replace `electric` with your version of ROS (probably indigo or jade).

According to the [wiki page for pr2_arm_navigation](http://wiki.ros.org/pr2_arm_navigation), the last version of ROS that it was documented or released for was Groovy.

You may be able to do the tutorial without using pr2_arm_navigation, or you may want to look for an equivalent tutorial from MoveIt, which is the current motion-planning library that is commonly used on the PR2.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0